# Species Distribution Modeling: Mammal river species

Tags: ecology, computational-model

When working with mammal river species, what parameters would you use to study them  (I have max and min temperature, average rain, slope and obstacles in the river)
Something like type of riparian forest?
Is there any good example of species distribution modelling of mammal river species?

Thanks, Héctor.

Comment: I think it will depend on what aspect of the species you are looking at. For example, if you want to model distribution to study predator-prey interaction, you might want to get information related to predator presence, geographical aspects (e.g. for helping camouflage) etc. In contrast if you want to study distribution for the purpose of migratory behavior, you can consider reproductive age, time and other ecological aspects etc. Their weight will depend of your goal.

Comment: I just tried "species distribution model river otter" (picking the first river-dwelling mammal I could think of) on Google Scholar and got quite a few hits ...

Comment: Mainly the aim is to know which is the  most negative parameter that is affecting it. Problem is that it is really associated to the river,  much more than the otter, depending its diet on athropods... (No data of arthropods), ¿Anything abiotic that could affect?(snow didn't affect...)

Comment: can you tell us what species you're interested in? voles? manatees?  river dolphins ... ????

Comment: Yes,  it's Galemys Pyrenaicus ( Pyrenean desman)  related to  moles